# Add date on Laravel

Tags: laravel

When i am using this code it shows an error "Call to a member function addDays() on string"

```
public function showJobCategoryContent($id)
{

    $jobsInfoById = DB::table('jobs')->where('category_id', '=', $id)->where('published', '=', 1)->paginate(3);

    $jobsInfoById = $jobsInfoById->map(function ($job) {
        return $job->created_at->addDays(30);
    });

    return $jobsInfoById->pluck('created_at');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using `DB` instead of `Jobs`, you are getting back raw database data instead of a carbon instance.  If you did the same thing with Jobs, you'd get models and the dates would be Carbon:

```
$jobsInfoById = Jobs::where('category_id', '=', $id)->where('published', '=', 1)->paginate(3);
```

To fix it without using Eloquent, do:

```
use Carbon\Carbon; //including Carbon already

$jobsInfoById = $jobsInfoById->map(function ($job) {
    return ['created_at' => Carbon::parse($job->created_at)->addDays(30)];
});
```

Carbon instance is created when you are doing the map on the result.

Comment: i am new on laravel so how can i do that. Is it possible to help me?

Comment: @RazBiswas check the update. If you get a carbon instance _but you need a date string_, then in the closure just change `->addDays(30)` as `->addDays(30)->toDateTimeString()` See http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting for more function if you need something different

Comment: So the changes I made is: `return ['created_at' => Carbon::parse($job->created_at)->addDays(30)];`

Comment: Thanks a lot @OmisakinOluwatobi now it show as a result like this [{"date":"2017-11-21 15:25:54.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},{"date":"2017-11-21 15:46:44.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},{"date":"2017-11-23 08:01:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"}] ====How i can print only Date..........Is it possible to help me.

Comment: @RazBiswas to print only date, as I said in my last comment change `->addDays(30)` to `->addDays(30)->toDateTimeString()`